# Which of following is correct regarding normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Which one of the following is true?

(A) If $G$ is an infinite group, then $G/N$ is an infinite group.

(B) If $G$ is a nonabelian group, then $G/N$ is a nonabelian group.

(C) If $G$ is a cyclic group, then $G/N$ is an abelian group.

(D) If $G$ is an abelian group, then $G/N$ is a cyclic group.

---

Attempt - I think correct option is  C .But i am not sure

Comment: Can you try to supply counterexamples to (A), (B) and (D)? Just asking for the right answer does not work here on MathStackExchange...

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is not true, consider $\frac{\mathbb Z}{2\mathbb Z}\cong \mathbb Z_2$

$B$ is not true $\frac{S_n}{A_n}\cong \mathbb Z_2$

$C$ is true, in fact we only need for $G$ to be abelian (all cyclic groups are abelian). $aNbN=(ab)N=(ba)N=bNaN$

$D$ is not true $\frac{\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2}{\mathbb Z_2\times\{0\}\times\{0\}}\cong \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$

Comment: Ah too bad that a solution was given away ... and for (B), that should be $\mathbb{Z}_2$ ...

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks.